# How to disable/enable users, based on sharepoint profiles, within a web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I'm working on an Sharepoint 2016 application with C# in the back end and Silverlight & angular .  I want to grant or deny permissions to users within specific web parts.  That is to say, I have a group of users with different permissions.  These permissions are set in 'Site Permissions' to have with either 'Read', 'Edit' or 'Full Control'.

A user who has 'Read' permissions currently can do anything in the system.  I'm assuming I can restrict certain web parts but I want to do more.  I want to disable access, say, if a web part has a button to alter data within a grid, within that web part, and a user has read only permissions.

Is this possible within Sharepoint 2016?

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve it by configuring Target Audiences for the web part.

You could create new audience in the user profile service application for the users who can use the web part.

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[How to create a SharePoint Global Audience for New Employees.](https://www.collaboris.com/creating-sharepoint-audience-new-employees/)

Then in the web part, you can select the audience which is created in user profile service application.

Only these users in the target audience in the web part can see and use the web part.

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Target content to specific audiences.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293)

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm trying to do.  I want to enable/disable links within a web part based on whatever permissions are set - not prevent a user from viewing it.